# Is there a way to test iOS builds on simulator without the source code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Our QA team wants to test our app on old versions of iOS.  We don't have devices with older versions, so we'd like to use xcode's simulator.  We'd like to avoid having them hook up to source control, get the latest, and build.  Instead, I'd like to just send them some file(s) that they can fire up in the simulator running some iOS version.  Obviously an ipa file won't work.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

If you open up Finder, and go to /Users/*user*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*iOS version*/Applications, you will find directories for all the apps installed on the simulator.

Just zip up that top level folder for the app, and have the other user drop it in the same directory.  Works like a charm.

NOTE: I think you may have to compile it for that specific version of iOS before sending it over to them.

Comment: There's no `iPhone Simulator` dir in my `Application Support` dir. The path has likely changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on doing this multiple times, I recommend you get a few cheap jailbroken devices and downgrade them into 3.1 or to the versions you want to QA on. There are lots of guides on that, like http://lifehacker.com/5572003/how-to-downgrade-your-iphone-3g[s]-from-ios-4-to-ios-313, and I'm sure many people want to get rid of their old iPhones.

The simulators and the real devices are not the same, and apple recommend you test with the real devices. for example, iPhone 3G with iOS 3.1 is much slower than the 3.1 simulator running on a mac.