# Install app on iphone simulator

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator

How can we install .app file into iphone simulator without having any source code?

Comment: Are you asking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this can be done.

If you open up Finder, and go to /Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/iOS version/Applications, you will find directories for all the apps installed on the simulator.

Just zip up that top level folder for the app, and have the other user drop it in the same directory. Works like a charm.

NOTE: I think you may have to compile it for that specific version of iOS before sending it over to them.

Source : [Is there a way to test iOS builds on simulator without the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015405/is-there-a-way-to-test-ios-builds-on-simulator-without-the-source-code)

Comment: but my question is how would i at very first place install an app for simulator?

Comment: @user1030258 : What is the difference ?

Comment: I am pretty new to automation.i am trying to setup iphone simulator for automating one the iphone app. And i dont know where to start from.

Comment: What are you talking about ? What relation beetween automation and your question ?

Comment: I need to install a particular app on iphone simulator for which later i m going to write automation test cases. Sorry if i have confused you. Basically i need to know how to install an application on iphone simulator without using source code

Comment: So... If you basically need to know how to install an application on iphone simulator without using source code but the binary, this is the answer... I really don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are three simple steps to install .app file on iOS simulator.

**STEP 1:Start iOS simulator** 
       There are two ways to start iOS simulator

```
   1. Using XCODE: Open Xcode and navigate to 
      **XCODE => Open Developer Tool => iOS Simulator**

   2: Using Terminal: Type following command in terminal 
      **open -a "iOS Simulator" --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <Device UDID>**
```

**Note:** Do not forget to change the DeviceUDID. You can check the UDID of running simulator by using following command:

> xcrun simctl list

The UDID is the alpha numeric value in highlighted box and when simulator will booted it’s status will be “Booted” instead of “Shutdown”.

**STEP 2: Installation:** 
        When device booted completely, use following command to install .app file in simulator

> **xcrun simctl install booted**

**STEP 3: Launch your app :** 
        You can launch your app by two ways 
        1. Tap on the app or 
        2. Write the following command on terminal

> **xcrun simctl launch booted**